# dns scapy server doesnt get the packet

Tags: dns, server, scapy

i need to send a packet using scapy to a dns server i made, and for some reason the server doesnt get the packet
this is the dns server

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from scapy.all import *
def le_check(p):
    return (DNS in p and p[0][DNSQR].qtype == 1 and p[0][UDP].dport==53)

def main():
     data_base = {'www.google.com': ('172.217.23.164','173.194.79.104','173.194.79.99')}

     p1=sniff(count=1, lfilter=le_check)



     x=p1[0][DNSQR].qname
     if x in data_base:
        list=data_base[x]
     else:
         list= "no such name"
     print p1[0][DNSQR].qname
     print list
     send(IP(dst=p1[0][IP].src)/UDP(sport=53, dport=53)/Raw(list))

     if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

code from scapy

```
 sendp(IP(dst=MY_IP)/UDP(sport=24601,dport=53)/DNS(qdcount=1,rd=1)/DNSQR(qname="www.google.com",qtype=1))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [i need to send a packet using scapy to a dns server i made, and for some reason the server doesnt get the packet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936455/i-need-to-send-a-packet-using-scapy-to-a-dns-server-i-made-and-for-some-reason)